# How to deinstall gcc-5-base

Tags: apt, dependencies, gcc

I have somehow installed gcc-5-base and now I am unable to deinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove gcc-5-base 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.1.0-0ubuntu11~14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-network : Depends: libqtdbus4 (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3~ubuntu6.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtgui4 : Depends: libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3~ubuntu6.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.1.0-0ubuntu11~14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

How can I fix this? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4):

*Please ... repeat after me and keep in mind:*

## No, I do not want to remove `gcc-5-base`!

You never did install `gcc-5-base`: the package ***is installed by Ubuntu*** and it has to be kept installed *or otherwise Ubuntu will cease to function!*

<sub>As you don't seem familiar with Ubuntu: What you're asking for is similar to removing the `system32` from the `Ẁindows` directory!</sub>

Comment: thanks!, I left it there, I though it came along with gcc 5.2 or something
I dont anyway understand the naming scheme of the stanart library? there is a libstdc++6? and other version for gcc4.8 and so on